# java.lang.stackoverflowerror when running Spark shell

Tags: apache-spark-sql

I tested the examples according to the docs in spark sql programming guide, but the `java.lang.stackoverflowerror` occurred everytime I called `sqlContext.sql("...")`.

Meanwhile, it worked fine in a `hiveContext`. The Hadoop version is 2.2.0, the Spark version is 1.1.0, built with Yarn, Hive.. I would be grateful if anyone could give me a hand.

```scala
scala> people.registerTempTable("people")

scala> val teenagers = sqlContext.sql("SELECT name FROM people WHERE age >= 13 AND age <= 19")
```

> java.lang.StackOverflowError  at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$$anon$3.apply(Parsers.scala:222)
>     at
>   scala.util.parsing.combinator.Parsers$Parser$$anonfun$append$1.apply(Parsers.scala:254)